# Applescript command encountering error after closing chrome window

Tags: if-statement, applescript, repeat

So I have been working on a project to mess around with some of my coding friends. I am trying to make an AppleScript application that tells Chrome to go back a page when run and I want it to run all the time. I have had to base it off of whether or not chrome has an active window open or not, I managed to get it to work so far but when I put in the repeated "Go back" command it comes up with an error message saying can't get window 1.

This is the code I am using. I am using High Sierra if that makes a difference.

```
repeat
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then
        repeat
            tell application "Google Chrome"
                if exists (window 1 of application "Google Chrome") then
                    repeat while exists (window 1 of application "Google Chrome")
                        go back tab of window 1
                    end repeat
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  This is not how to implement a *stay-open* script.  Doing endless repeat loops with no means of exiting them is just going to devour system resources and make *Google Chrome* unusable until the script is forced to quit.

Also, the code is horrific: lots of redundant statements and confusing syntax.

You would better achieve your aim by creating what is called a ***stay-open*** application script, which will use the `idle` handler to process commands every few seconds or so.  As the name implies, the script will stay open and execute the commands until you tell it to quit.

Start by declaring a property that determines how often the `idle` handler is called.  This is defined at the bottom, following a `run` handler, which executes upon running of the script and calls the `idle` handler.

```
    property idleTime : 20 --seconds


    on run

        idle

    end run


    on idle

        tell application "Google Chrome"
            if it is not running then return idleTime

            tell window 1 to if it exists then ¬
                tell its active tab
                    if its URL contains "disney" then ¬
                        tell me to quit

                    set its URL to "chrome://newtab/"
                end tell
        end tell

        return idleTime

    end idle
```

I slightly modified the joke you're pulling on your friends, because `go back` will only work so many times before you reach the end of the history and there's no further back one can go.  Instead, I told the tab to load up the *New Tab* starting page every 20 seconds, which I'm sure will be very confusing for the user.

In order to get it up and running properly, you need to save the script as an *Application*, and check the box that marks it as a *stay open* script.  Then simply double click to run it.

There are two ways to terminate this script: ① Open *Activity Monitor* and terminate its process from the list of running processes; or ② Visit [Disney.com](http://disney.com) (or any Disney website) in *Chrome* and wait 20 seconds.

Comment: @JosiahHolgate You're very welcome. If you're happy, could I ask you to thank me by selecting my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply save this code as a stay open application.

```
on idle
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if it is not running then return 10 -- seconds to wait before repeating
        tell window 1 to if it exists then ¬
            try
                go back active tab
            end try
    end tell
    return 10  -- seconds to wait before repeating
end idle
```

Comment: Back to the serious topic of answering questions on a community-driven exchange site, one thing I realise I failed to do in my contribution was to actually identify and explain ***why*** the OP’s script threw the specific error it did, re: unable to get `window 1`?  I want to say it’s got something to do with the way its existence was tested for: `if exists window 1` rather than `tell window 1 to if it exists`.  But I can’t rationalise why one would work and the other not.  What do you think?  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In one of the variations of the script I was going to post in my answer, and as per your example using the quit command, I was not able to quit the stay open application from the dock unless I added the Quit handler

Comment: if exists of window 1 then ¬ tell its window 1 ¬ tell its active tab..  Will function correctly..  In other words just checking if window 1 exists... we still need to tell window 1 to tell its active tab... whereas... tell window 1 to if it exists... is targeting window 1 ... Right off the bat

Comment: That was neither my question nor the OP’s.  I don’t see any confusion over the need to target the commands to `window 1` (and subsequently its tab).  The OP’s error message was along the lines of `window 1` not being able to be retrieved/referenced/etc.  This implies that a reference to `window 1` was made either using incorrect syntax (so neglecting to address its parents, for example, before addressing it); or the reference was made at a point where there was no `window 1`. *Cont’d…*

Comment: The OP referenced the object hierarchy in order, so it’s unlikely to be the former reason that’s to blame.  That leaves the issue arising from `window 1` not existing, such as when *Chrome* isn’t running.  However, he tests to see if `window 1` exists in a similar manner to how you and I have done, but slightly differently.  I was wondering whether it’s this difference in syntax that causes the issue, and, if so, why that would be.  That is, is there anything inherently incorrect about the way the OP has chosen to check whether or not `window 1` exists ?  If there is, I can’t see it.